# D365 FinOps View Range Error : "Query extended range failure: Expected identifier near pos"

Tags: sql, axapta, x++, aot, dynamics-365-operations

Getting this error when browsing the view using `SysTableBrowser`
[image: Error in Browser]

Seems to be coming from the range I've added in the View:
[image: View Details]

```
((PersonUser.VALIDFROM <= Heu_UserInfo.today) && (PersonUser.VALIDTO >= Heu_UserInfo.today))
```

The build and sync is fine and the SQL View is coming correct.
[image: SQL View]

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are selecting T2's fields ("T2.ValidFrom" and "T2.ValidTo") for your selection fields

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it will help, but could be worth trying `date2StrXpp(ValidTo)` in case your ValidTo / ValidFrom / Today fields are of the Date data type. If you use query expressions in code this conversion is needed so could be needed in AOT queries too. Haven't double checked this myself however.